# Allow only number in text box based on consecutive id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/HkEuf/1/) which will allow only to numbers.

I want to do this in based on id.

So i created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HkEuf/5740/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //called when key is pressed in textbox
  $("#quantity").keypress(function (e) {
     //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        //display error message
        $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
               return false;
    }
   });
});
```

How can i do this for a series of id like quantity1,quantity2, like this..

**Update :**

I can't use class name.. How can i do it only by `id`

Comment: use class names - `$(.quantity)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you've to do is to match all the id's which is simple. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HkEuf/5743/).

Here's the part code -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //called when key is pressed in textbox
    $("[id^=quantity]").keypress(function (e) {
     //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        //display error message
        $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
               return false;
    }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HkEuf/5742/)

Try this

HTML

```
Number : <input type="text" name="quantity" class= "numberonly" id="quantity1" />
Number1 : <input type="text" name="quantity" class= "numberonly"  id="quantity2" />
Number1 : <input type="text" name="quantity" class= "numberonly"  id="quantity3" />

&nbsp;<span id="errmsg"></span>
```

Jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    for(var i = 1; i< 4 ;i++)
    {
    //called when key is pressed in textbox
    $("#quantity"+i).keypress(function (e) {
      //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
      if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        //display error message
        $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
               return false;
        }
     });
    }
  });
```

Comment: I have updated my question.. i.e., only by using `id` and not by using class name